# find polygons within a radius of one point (of a table of points)

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'd like to perform a select by location analysis in PostGIS that first selects the geometry of ONE point out of a table (of many points). Creates then a circumference around it and checks which geometries (polygons) of a second table lie within that circumference.

I came up with this but am somehow stuck..

```
SELECT t2.name, t2_area
FROM ( SELECT geom
       FROM views.sites
       WHERE site_id LIKE 'AB_10003' ) t1, spatial.land_use t2
WHERE ST_DWithin(t1.geom, t2.geom, 1000) -- radius of 1000m
```

the SRID of my geometries is 31467. Any help?

Comment: how are you stuck?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: One immediate observation is that LIKE 'AB_10003' will only match AB_10003, as there is no wildcard, %, so it is possible that your subquery, t1, returns nothing? Hard to know, as somehow stuck isn't wildly  informative.

Comment: OK. Sry, I just realized that my t2.geom has 0 as SRID value.

Comment: So problem solved?

Comment: yes, problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your SQL looks logically correct, it's not well formed. You are thinking procedurally, and you should think more schematically. In "correct" SQL your logic would be:

```sql
SELECT sl.name, sl.area
FROM views.sites vs
JOIN spatial.land_use sl
ON ST_DWithin(vs.geom, sl.geom, 1000)
WHERE vs.site_id = 'AB_10003'
```

Use "join" clauses for conditions that use values from two tables, and put other conditions into the "where" clause, and then let the database sort out the most efficient execution path: it will do better than you.

Comment: thanks for the input!
Since I have selected only one row (one site_id) of the **vs** table, I can't add additional columns of it referring to other site_ids (sl.site_id) than **'AB_10003'**. Is there a possibility to use **'AB_10003'** only for the ST_DWithin() - argument and also add a JOIN argument like `vs.site_id = sl.site_id`? E.g. adding a column vs.stream that contains the stream name of each site_id that was selected

Comment: I wrapped the query above in another query  and joined the vs table again to be able to get the stream names for each site_id.